# Multiple Filters with the same table

Tags: powerbi

I've been struggling with this and I hope you can help me.

I have a table related to expenses with supplies and external services, personnel expenses and other expenses of a company.
This table has a column with the accounting accounts according, a column with the respective cost center, that is, administrative cost center, production cost center and others and a column with the amount of each of these accounts.

I want to make 2 filters to reach an amount, a filter on the ledger account for example 64 and a filter for a set of cost centers.

Here is the measure that isn't working

```
General Equipment =
```

CALCULATE(

```
    SUMX(
    FILTER(Financialcostcenter,
    CONTAINSSTRING(Financialcostcenter[CostCenter] IN {"BF01080600", "BF01080100", "BF01080200", "BF02080000", "BF03080000", "BR_PROD_01", "BR2_PROD01", "BR3_PROD01","GR_PROD_01", "FR_PROD_01"} "BR_PROD_01")
    && Financialcostcenter [2 dígitos]= 64),
    Financialcostcenter [amount]),
DATESYTD(Datas[Date])
```

)

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you add some sample data with your expected output from them?

Comment: I put an example box on the link of the official publication.

In this example:
I want the total cost of production equipment only, in this case it would be the sum of the total of the two lines that are underlined in yellow.
 To get there then I have to filter the official account or the 2-digit account and still filter by the cost center.

Comment: Hi @Mariana, please check my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still giving an error.
The error says:

"Error Message:
MdxScript (Model) (951, 17) Calculation error in measure 'DR' [General Equipment]: DAX comparison operations do not support comparison values ​​of type Text with values ​​of type Integer. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values. "

Do you know how I can solve it?

Comment: please check the changed code where I converted 64 to "64" to make it string.

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't provide any sample data and your expected output, I guess you need a measure like below for your purpose-

> You can add as many filter as you need in the code
> This is also possible to use OR in place of AND if required

```
General Equipment = 
CALCULATE(
    SUMX(
        FILTER(
            Financialcostcenter,
            CONTAINSSTRING(
                Financialcostcenter[CostCenter] IN {"BF01080600", "BF01080100", "BF01080200", "BF02080000", "BF03080000","BR_PROD_01", "BR2_PROD01", "BR3_PROD01","GR_PROD_01", "FR_PROD_01", "BR_PROD_01"}
            )
            && Financialcostcenter [2 dígitos]= "64"
            //-- You can also add more filter like below
            && Financialcostcenter [Description]= "Production equipment"
        ),
        Financialcostcenter [amount]
    ),
    DATESYTD(Datas[Date])
)
```

Comment: If your "2 digitos" data type is string, you can apply the checking as = "64". In case of numeric data type, it should worked as earlier.